# Генерируется исключение

Tags: python, django

Исключение:

```
self.assertNotContains(response, self.post1.text) AssertionError: 1 != 0 : Response should not contain 'test message'
```

Код:

```
class FollowTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.user1 = User.objects.create_user(
            username="first_user",
            password="firstuserpass",
        )
        self.post1 = Post.objects.create(
            text="test message", author=self.user1,
        )
        self.user2 = User.objects.create_user(
            username="second_user",
            password="seconduserpass",
        )
        self.user3 = User.objects.create_user(
            username="third_user",
            password="thirduserpass",
        )
 
    def test_following_unfollowing_user(self):
        self.client.force_login(self.user1)
        user2_profile = self.client.get(
            reverse("profile", args=[self.user2.username]
            ))
        self.assertContains(user2_profile, "Подписаться")
        follow_user2 = self.client.get(
            reverse("profile_follow", args=[self.user2.username]
            ))
        count_follow = Follow.objects.count()
        self.assertEqual(count_follow, 1)
        user2_profile = self.client.get(
            reverse("profile", args=[self.user2.username]
            ))
        self.assertContains(user2_profile, "Отписаться")
        unfollow_user2 = self.client.get(
            reverse("profile_unfollow", args=[self.user2.username]
            ))
        count_follow = Follow.objects.count()
        self.assertEqual(count_follow, 0)
 
 
    def test_post_follow(self):
        self.client.force_login(self.user2)
        follow_user1 = self.client.get(
            reverse("profile_follow", args=[self.user1.username]
            ))
        count_follow = Follow.objects.count()
        self.assertEqual(count_follow, 1)
        response = self.client.get(reverse("follow_index"))
        self.assertContains(response, self.post1.text)
        self.client.force_login(self.user3)
        response = self.client.get(reverse("follow_index"))
        self.assertNotContains(response, self.post1.text)
```

Ошибка:

```
self.assertNotContains(response, self.post1.text) AssertionError: 1 != 0 : Response should not contain 'test message'
```

Comment: может быть в `response`, действительно есть фраза `test message`?

Comment: Думаю, следует начать с того, что это не исключение. Потом нужно посмотреть, что находится в response и делать выводы.